Cypress for React: How to stub a function being called indirectly?
I want to stub a function in my Cypress component test, which gets called by other function to make a call to a database.
// /utils/common.ts
export const callDB = async (params: any[]): Promise<string> = {
  // function code
}


// /utils/other.ts
export const otherFunction = async (params: any[]): Promise<string> = {
  await callDB(params);
}

The component Databse.tsx makes a call to otherFunction which makes a call to callDB.
I want to stub the response of callDB but my stubbed function gets ignored.
Here is the setup of my Cypress component test:
// Cypress Component Test
import { useState } from 'react';
import Database from 'src/components/Database';
import * as common from 'src/utils/common'; 

describe('Call Database', () => {
  let stateSpy: Cypress.Agent<sinon.SinonSpy>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.stub(common, 'callDB').callsFake((contractParams) => {
      if (contractParams.row === 'id') {
        return Promise.resolve('MockedId');
      }else {
        return Promise.resolve('123');
      }
    });

    const Wrapper = () => {
      const [state, setState] = useState({
        id: '',
      });

      stateSpy = cy.spy(setState);


      return (
        <Database
          setState={setState}
        />
      );
    };

    cy.mount(<Wrapper />, { routerProps: { initialEntries: ['/'] } });

  });

  it('should stub the correct values', () => {
    // Code to see which values are used
  });
});

Database.tsx still makes call to the actual database.
